# how to convert rgb to html color code in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have rgb color code in database is differ from the percentage value, and i pass the table via json parser, my question is how to convert `rgb` to `HTML` color code.

example `255 255 255 255` in my database.

How to convert in my program and how to set color in `R.id.l7`.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, },
            new int[] {
                     R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7});


            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what does  "how to set color in R.id.l7" mean ?

Comment: @blackbelt R.id.l7 is the textview in list

Comment: @blackbelt any possible to set color using ui programming?

Comment: the you should learn how to override the `getView` method

Comment: @blackbelt how to convert rgb to html color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a ARGB color in its html representation you could use:

```
int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
String htmlColor = String.format("#%X", color);
```

if you want back the color in its int representation you can use:

```
int color = Color.parse(htmlColor);
```

Comment: `String.format("#%08X", color)` if you want to ensure that a color with alpha 0 is printed as ARGB.